# Bootstrap Website Maybe Not Loading with Iphone 6?

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter-bootstrap

I not sure at this point if I have a problem with my own website for users of iphone 6.

http://www.dataanalytica.systems

It seems to work fine on the computers and on my iphone 5.

However, when my sister tried to view the site with her iphone 6, the page simple won’t load at all.

Can anyone with an iphone 6 please check if it loads on their phone.
If no, any suggestions as to why would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing on website. I checked using desktop. Blank page

Comment: This is getting more worrying!   I can see it fine on my computer and I phone.
Can other people continue to check on various devices then please.   Please specify what browsers you are using if there is a problem.

Comment: If I access the URL with `curl --verbose`, I see "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" and "Content-Length: 0" in the returned headers.

Comment: Ok, I’ve spent several hours now looking into this but with no definitive conclusion.  I have swapped a few bits of coding around in the head section but it all still looks good at my end.  I have also used a website called http://mobiletest.me and all looks good. 
Thus, if anyone still can’t load this site please tell me what browser + version you are using, operating system and any other info you think might be helpful.
It is very difficult for me to address this when I can’t get it not to work.  It must be something very subtle.  Any additional ideas welcome.
Thanks for input thus far.

Comment: Turns out it was a database access error (insufficient access).  Fixed now but thanks for all help given.  This problem is now closed.